# CSS Problem when printing Menu

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I had a Menu which is functionally doing well. But in the master page where I'm aligning my menu, It takes a line space for itself and also starts at the middle of page(not exactly middle of the page but 10 spaces from left.

This is my CSS:

```
.menu {
}
.menu ul {
    list-style:none;
}
.menu li {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:53px;
    line-height:53px;
}
.menu li a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#852917;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:53px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 25px;
    background:#ebdbca url(menu_037_bg.jpg) no-repeat left;
    border-bottom:2px solid #d7a278;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#a73e29 url(menu_037_h.jpg) no- repeat left;
    border-bottom:2px solid #b75542;
}
.menu li a.current {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    background:#a73e29 url(images/menu_037_h.jpg) no- repeat left;
    border-bottom:2px solid #b75542;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:53px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li a:hover.current {
    color: #fff;
}
```

This is the menu:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="background-color: #001A65; height: 7px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="background-color: #CFB549; height: 10px; text-align: right;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:menu onmenuitemclick="menu_navigate" id="Menu1" orientation="Horizontal" runat="Server" width="100%" cssclass="menu" includestyleblock="false" renderingmode="List" staticmenuitemstyle-itemspacing="10px">
        <staticmenuitemstyle bordercolor="Black" borderstyle="Solid" borderwidth="0px" horizontalpadding="20px"/>
        </asp:menu>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Can u guys help me out. I'm on this for almost an hour and not been able to figure it out..

Comment: You might want to include the rendered HTML, rather than the unprocessed/unrendered ASPX page, since the rendered HTML is what the CSS will be operating on.

Comment: Can you show the issue using jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what you are describing?  Having trouble picturing what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I usually hide my menus when they are printed as it is not as though any one can use them. In order to do so just put this in one of your head tags, using the proper class:

```
@media print {
    menu { display: none; }
}
```

If you want the menu to print you can use the media type of print to fix any errors that come up.